# In a bash script, if I have two vars with grep results can I delete lines on var 1 not in var 2?

Tags: bash, grep

In a bash script I have two variables (A and B) that have results from a `grep` operation. I want to delete all lines in variable A that don't appear anywhere in variable B (even as part of a line). Is this possible?

For example:

Variable A:

```
one
two
three
```

Variable B:

```
one day
three weeks
```

Result:

```
two
```

Comment: What do you mean by *even as part of a line*? How many letters could consist of *"a part"*

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: Do you "want to delete all lines in variable A that don't appear anywhere in variable B (even as part of a line)" as you ask, or do you want the list of lines to delete, as in your "Result:" example?

Answer (score 0):

Use `$B` as the pattern in another `grep` command. Use the `-v` option to get lines that don't match.

```
A='Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Suspendisse imperdiet, 
orci ac turpis duis.'
B='ipsum
perd'
new_A=$(grep -F -v "$B" <<<"$A")
echo "$new_A"
```

Output:

```
consectetur adipiscing elit. 
orci ac turpis duis.
```

Answer (score 0):

clear IGNORECASE = 1, if you want case sensitive match

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
A=$'one\ntwo\nthree'
B=$'one\nday\nthree\nweeks'
awk -v compareSTR="$B" '
BEGIN { split(compareSTR, compareLines, "\n"); IGNORECASE = 1 }
{
found=0;

for (i in compareLines)
   {
   if (index(compareLines[i],$0))
      {
      found=1;
      break;
      }
   }
if (!found) print $0;
}' <<< $A
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question you *asked* -
If I read your specs correctly:

```
$: A=$'one\ntwo\nthree\n'
$: B=$'one day\nthree weeks\n'
$: echo "$A"
one
two
three

$: echo "$B"
one day
three weeks
```

To "*delete* all lines in variable A that **don't** appear anywhere in variable B (even as part of a line)", and return `$A` with those lines removed:

```
$: grep -o -f <(echo "$A") <(echo "$B") # 'two' does NOT appear in $B
one
three
```

This because `-o` returns only the matched pattern on a line by itself. the `-f` is reading its match pattern list from a "file", and the `<( )` constructs are returning the output of the `echo` commands as filesystem elements.

To get the list of lines to delete (as in your example, instead of your request), you need two `grep`s:

```
$: grep -vf <( grep -o -f <(echo "$A") <(echo "$B") ) <( echo "$A")
two
```

To do that in one pass, instead of two `grep`s each effectively reading two "files", use `awk`:

```
$: awk 'NR==FNR{B=B$0} NR>FNR&&B~$1{print}' <(echo "$B") <(echo "$A")
one
three
```

To change the contents of your variables, effectively "deleting" `two` from `$A`, just reassign:

```
$: A=$( grep -of <(echo "$A") <(echo "$B") )
$: echo "$A"
one
three
```

though I'd probably put it in a different var, depending on requirements.

To do the same thing in a maybe more novice-friendly form:

```
$: echo "$A">A; echo "$B">B; A=$( grep -of A B ); echo "$A"
one
three
```

Or, borrowing the cleaner string-processing logic from Barmar,

```
$: A=$( grep -oF "$A" <<< "$B" )
$: echo "$A"
one
three
```

---

But honestly, this sounds like an [X/Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info/), where you are asking about something that isn't really representative of your resources and goals so much as the current state of your attempt.

If you are working with files, it might be better to just work with files than to wrangle the data into variables and try to mangle it there. (See my file-based simplification, above.)